# Call EasyJSWebView from storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview

Check this code

Storyboard 
---UIViewController1
---UIViewController2

---UIViewController1 contain a button on press call ---UIViewController2 
and in ---UIViewController2 i need to open EasyJSwebviewSample code

Reference code -
https://github.com/dukeland/EasyJSWebViewSample/blob/master/EasyJSWebViewSample/MyJSInterface.m

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a UIWebView inside UIViewController2 then use below code.
then add below code in UIViewController2 to run the EasyJSWebView code.

```
MyJSInterface* interface = [MyJSInterface new];
[self.myWebView addJavascriptInterfaces:interface WithName:@"MyJSTest"];
[interface release];
```

MyJSInterface is derived NSObject class its not a VC.

Note: WKWebView provides native bridge between javascript and objective c see this SO URL [Call JavaScript function from native code in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049343/call-javascript-function-from-native-code-in-wkwebview)

Comment: not working! can you able to change the name of MyJSTest with some other name?

Comment: Why do you need to change the name , are you adding MyJSInterface class to your project?