# WKWebView. didStartProvisionalNavigation not called

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I'm using `WKWebView` in my app and everything works fine until user is going to [money.cnn.com](http://money.cnn.com). For the main page of this site everything is fine as well but when user leaves the main page and goes for example to http://money.cnn.com/2016/11/21/news/dubai-trump-golf-course-developer/index.html?iid=hp-toplead-intl or any other page on this site the delegate methods `didStartProvisionalNavigation` and `didCommitNavigation` not called. But I need these methods in order to detect the start of a navigation. `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` is called at the very beginning however it is called multiple times and I feel that using this method is not a perfect solution. So my question is: what can I do in such a situation? What so especial can be at that site what doesn't make `WKWebView` call its delegate methods and what may be a reliable solution in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know very well web development, but it seems to me that the problem with JavaScript of the money.cnn.com site. It seems that the transitions between the site pages and their loading is carried out with help of JavaScript. That JavaScript conflict with native WKWebView handlers.

But! You can inject your own JavaScript with handler at the beginning of the page. And when the page begins to open, the script will work first.

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Full example code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    private weak var webView: WKWebView?
    private lazy var scriptName = "GetUrl"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupWebView()
        loadUrl(string: "http://money.cnn.com/2016/11/21/news/dubai-trump-golf-course-developer/index.html?iid=hp-toplead-intl")
    }

    func setupWebView() {
        let contentController = WKUserContentController();
        let script = "webkit.messageHandlers.\(scriptName).postMessage(document.URL)"
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        contentController.add(self, name: scriptName)

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        let webView = WKWebView(frame:  UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView = webView
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == scriptName {
            guard let url = message.body as? String else { return }
            if url.contains("http://money.cnn.com/") {
                print("!!! \(url)")
            } else {
                print("??? \(url)")
            }
        }
    }

    func loadUrl(string: String) {
        guard   let url = URL(string: string),
                let webView = self.webView else { return }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

### Info.plist

add in your Info.plist transport security setting

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

or

[image]

### Result

[image]

### More

[Call JavaScript function from native code in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730365/4488252)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not working. It is working if I use it the way your example does - explicitly loading request. It works for the main page of the site. However when I go from money.cnn.com to http://money.cnn.com/2016/11/21/news/dubai-trump-golf-course-developer/index.html?iid=hp-toplead-intl or any other subpage the delegate method is not invoked. The only that I can do is pass false into forMainFrameOnly then it works too but it leads to invoking the delegate method too often for loading every resource at the page

Comment: it is very strange. I made small fix and added screenshot of the console. Take a look. In my example, the script is triggered before each page is displayed.

Comment: Created a new project from scratch and just copypasted your code there. Works only for the first page i.e. when load explicitly called. If I browse further userContentController didReceive message method is never invoked)))

Comment: in func userContentController() we detect only http://money.cnn.com/ pages (edit this function to show all urls). May be you open another cnn website?

Comment: no, the method itself is not called. I checked that of course

Comment: I have no idea why this code works you not like me (may be some magic...). Try my project. https://www.dropbox.com/s/23sqo13gsqqiodm/stackoverflow-40722457.zip?dl=0

Comment: Got it working. It was simple - just run on a device instead of simulator. Who could think? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, one more question (I can make it a separate question if you want to gain more reputation). Is there any possibility to distinguish between a script injected at document start and document end? Can't seem to find any answer. I need to know when the loading is over as well

Comment: Yes. You need to inject several scripts. I will make a sample to you.

Comment: I've created two ones already. I just have no chance to make out which one is invoking delegate method currently

Comment: so easy. script name is custom. I should have guessed it myself. thanks a lot, buddy

Answer (score 0):

Set Delegate like:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```