# How to get url from webview whenever user move to other pages

Tags: swift, url, webview, notifications, nsurl

How can I get a URL from webView whenever the URL is changed?

I want to change the button color when current URL is changed. So I need to check the current URL all the time.

And I also would like to get URL value as a String.

I tried the below code but it doesn't work at all.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(urlChecker), name: NSNotification.Name.NSURLCredentialStorageChanged, object: webView)
```

Comment: did you check: https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

#### 1. Solution

**UIWebViewDelegate**

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview

```
optional func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, 
  shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, 
       navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

**UIWebViewNavigationType:**

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewnavigationtype

don't forget to return `true`

> `case linkClicked`
>
> User tapped a link.
>
> `case formSubmitted`
>
> User submitted a form.
>
> `case backForward`
>
> User tapped the back or forward button.
>
> `case reload`
>
> User tapped the reload button.
>
> `case formResubmitted`
>
> User resubmitted a form.
>
> `case other`
>
> Some other action occurred.

#### 2. Solution

Inject Javascript JavaScript MessageHandler

(credit to [Vasily Bodnarchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4488252/vasily-bodnarchuk))

Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730365/1930509

> Swift 3 example.
>
> ### Description
>
> The script is inserted into page which will displayed in WKWebView.
>   This script will return the page URL (but you can write another
>   JavaScript code). This means that the script event is generated on the
>   web page, but it will be handled in our function:
>
> ```
> func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {...}
> ```
>
> ### Full Code example
>
> ```
> import UIKit
> import WebKit
>
> class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
>
>     var webView = WKWebView()
>     let getUrlAtDocumentStartScript = "GetUrlAtDocumentStart"
>     let getUrlAtDocumentEndScript = "GetUrlAtDocumentEnd"
> ```

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()

            let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            config.addScript(script: WKUserScript.getUrlScript(scriptName: getUrlAtDocumentStartScript),
 scriptHandlerName:getUrlAtDocumentStartScript, scriptMessageHandler:
 self, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart)
            config.addScript(script: WKUserScript.getUrlScript(scriptName: getUrlAtDocumentEndScript),
scriptHandlerName:getUrlAtDocumentEndScript, scriptMessageHandler:
self, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd)


             webView = WKWebView(frame:  UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: config)
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
             view.addSubview(webView)
        }

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)
         webView.loadUrl(string: "http://apple.com")
    }
}
```

> ```
> extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
>     func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
>         switch message.name {
>
>             case getUrlAtDocumentStartScript:
>                 print("start: \(message.body)")
>
>             case getUrlAtDocumentEndScript:
>                 print("end: \(message.body)")
>
>             default:
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> extension WKUserScript {
>     class func getUrlScript(scriptName: String) -> String {
>         return "webkit.messageHandlers.\(scriptName).postMessage(document.URL)"
>     }
> }
>
> extension WKWebView {
>     func loadUrl(string: String) {
>         if let url = URL(string: string) {
>             load(URLRequest(url: url))
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

```
 extension WKWebViewConfiguration {
        func addScript(script: String, scriptHandlerName:String, scriptMessageHandler: WKScriptMessageHandler,injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTime) {
             let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: injectionTime, forMainFrameOnly: false)
             userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
             userContentController.add(scriptMessageHandler, name: scriptHandlerName)
        }
    }
```

> ### Info.plist
>
> add in your Info.plist transport security setting
>
> ```
> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
> <dict>
>     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
>     <true/>
> </dict>
> ```
>
> ### Result

[image]

> ### Resources ##

[Document Object Properties and Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)