# Detect when WKWebView is finished loading

Tags: swift, wkwebview

How can I detect when my `WKWebView` is finished loading so that I can fetch the URL from it such as using the delegate method?

I implemented the delegate method for the `WKWebView` but I can't detect when it is finish loading the video.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let preference = WKPreferences()
        preference.javaScriptEnabled = true
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preference
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        view.addSubview(webView)

        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.youtube.com")!))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("finish loading video")
    }    
}
```

But the method above is not called when it finishes loading the video from YouTube.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40730365/4488252

Answer (score 8):

**SWIFT 4:**

Use following delegate method of WKNavigationDelegate. Where you can check is finished loading ?? And here you can get URL loaded in webView.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish  navigation: WKNavigation!) 
{
    let url = webView.url?.absoluteString
    print("---Hitted URL--->\(url!)") // here you are getting URL
}
```

Comment: I think this method must be used for the start loading detection. And for the end: func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)

Comment: The delegate method you have used is called when the webView "begins" to receive content, not when its finished loading. The correct delegate method to use is "webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)"