# Swift 3 - Check if WKWebView has loaded page

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, webkit, wkwebview

**My question**:
*How do I check if a page in WKWebView has fully loaded in Xcode using Swift 3?*

This is my problem:

*Webpage 1:* 
From this page I load Webpage 2

*Webpage 2:*
I need to get html data from Webpage 2, but when I print the HTML data I get HTML data of webpage 1, which I don't want. But when I print HTML data 2 seconds later it gives me the right HTML data.

I need to know whether or not a page in WKWebView did finish loading. I can see in the WebView it is loaded and also the progressbar is fully loaded, but when I print html data of the page I get html data of previous page, which is not what I want. Only if I wait a second it gives the right data, probably cause Webpage 2 is loaded.

So how do I let Xcode to print html when the next page is totally loaded?

I have tried several methods:

- [detect WKWebView finish loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797029/detect-wkwebview-finish-loading)
- [Call JavaScript function from native code in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049343/call-javascript-function-from-native-code-in-wkwebview/40730365#40730365)

Maybe I can use:

if webView.isloading { get }
but I don't know how to implement this method and if it should work.
I have tried several methods from Stack but these are not working for me or outdated.

Do you guys know a solution for this problem in Swift 3? 
Thanks!

Comment: In the first question you linked, it mentions the use of `WKNavigationDelegate`, and also `func webView(WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!)`, did they help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It didn't help for me, but maybe I don't know how to implement this methods the right way. Do you know how to implement this method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview ?

Comment: To use that method, make your view controller class conform to the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol, then implement that method inside your view controller class. There should be examples online [such as this](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/creating-simple-browser-with-wkwebview.html).

Comment: Thanks @paulvs ! Didn't know it was that easy to implement a method from apple documentation!

Comment: @Stef You should mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 77):

**Answer (Big thanks to @paulvs )**

To check if your WKWebView has loaded easily implement the following method:

```
import WebKit
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {


  let webView = WKWebView()


  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
    didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("loaded")
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.yourwebsite.com/") !
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

}
```

1. Add WKNavigationDelegate to class
2. Add:

   ```
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) { print("loaded") }
   ```

Result: It will print "loaded" in the console everytime the WKWebView has finished loading the page. This was excactly what I was looking for, so again a big thanks to Paulvs!

Comment: this is not correct, it is per each resource, but not for the whole page with all the resources;

Comment: also there might be redirects which also needs additional treatment

Comment: Missed adding this line: webView.navigationDelegate = self; -- works perfectly after adding!

Answer (score 32):

> Set delegate > [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)

**Objective-C**

```
// Start loading WKWebView
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSLog(@"Start loading");
} 

//Finished loading WKWebView
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSLog(@"End loading");
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Start loading")    
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("End loading")
}
```