# Removing/Stripping HTML Class from WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to remove header-padding HTML Class from WKWebview , This is the method i am using currently .

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView,didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation){


    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('[header-padding​]').remove();", completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in

    })

}
```

But it does't work , here is my HTML .

```
<div class="header-padding" style="padding-bottom: 104px;">
<div class="navigation nav"><div class="nav-overlay"></div>

<header class="global-header">
<button class="search" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="show search field">
    <span class="search-icon"></span>
</button>
<button class="burger" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="show main menu">
    <span class="burger-menu"></span>
</button>
<a href="/content/insite.html" class="logo">
    <img class="logo-img" src="/etc/logo.png" alt="">
</a>

<div class="profile" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="profileNavImg">
    <img id="header_profile_image" class="avatar profileLayoutCircle profile-show" src="/content/dam" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any Help would be really Great . Thanks

Comment: I think this answer should help you [Call JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730365/6689101)

Comment: Your Javascript was wrong. I think it should be `document.querySelector('.header-padding').remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the incorrect query selector. To select an element by it's class, you should use a `.`:

```
document.querySelector('.header-padding').remove();
```