# How to Evaluate JavaScript with Swift - Getting nil for all values (evertime: even is path is correct)

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to simply evaluate the Javascript, but it comes up with an error. I simply want to print everything inside of *'container title'*.

Hey I'm getting an error with this code:

```
WebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-js').getElementsByClassName('container title')[0].innerHTML"){ (value, error) in
if error != nil {
    print("Error = \(String(describing: error))")
} else {
    print("Success = \(String(describing: value))")
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

**(Note - I know how to evaluate Javascript with Swift, but can't seem to figure this one out)**

I'm Getting nil for all values (evertime: even is path is correct).

My WebView is set up like this:

```
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true

    // Create a configuration for the preferences
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences

    voiceWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: page3View.frame.width * 0.0, y: page3View.frame.height * 0.0, width: page3View.frame.width, height: page3View.frame.height), configuration: configuration)
    voiceWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    voiceWebView.uiDelegate = self
    voiceWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    voiceWebView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    voiceWebView.alpha = 1.0

    page3View.insertSubview(voiceWebView, at: 0)
    page3View.bringSubview(toFront: voiceWebView)

    voiceWebView.load(URLRequest(url: NSURL(string:"https://test.com")! as URL))
```

**Update:**

This prints *nil*

```
document.getElementsByClassName('container title').innerHTML
```

Also

```
document.getElementsByClassName('container title')[0].innerHTML
```

This alone error out this  -

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049343/call-javascript-function-from-native-code-in-wkwebview

Comment: also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('mdl-js')` returns an array of elements.. you are then chaining `getElementsByClassName` again to get `containerTitle`??

Comment: updated Answer @Brandon